# SOLR Error 500: default search field 'name' not defined or not indexed

Tags: solr

While I was trying to upgrade from Solr 3.5 to 4.6, I encountered this error.

```
{msg=SolrCore 'core0' is not available due to init failure: default search field 'name' not defined or not indexed. Schema file is /opt/jetty/solr/./cores/core0/schema.xml,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'core0' is not available due to init failure: default search field 'name' not defined or not indexed. Schema file is /opt/jetty/solr/./cores/core0/schema.xml
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:818)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:289)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1338)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:484)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:620)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: default search field 'name' not defined or not indexed. Schema file is /opt/jetty/solr/./cores/core0/schema.xml
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:608)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.(IndexSchema.java:166)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:554)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:592)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:271)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:263)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: default search field 'name' not defined or not indexed
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:507)
    ... 15 more
,code=500}

**On my schema.xml**

```
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

**On my data-config.xml**

```
<field column="name" name="name"/>
```

I already did tried to comment out those fields then restart jetty server but no specific errors even on log files.

Comment: That schema field is set up in `/opt/jetty/solr/cores/core0/schema.xml` and not a schema.xml somewhere else, right?

Comment: yes correct since this is multi-core.

Comment: Strange.  Is that schema field showing up properly when you check the running schema in the admin web ui?

Comment: At a first glance this looks like a SOLR bug - have you poked their developers?

Comment: @ShaneMadden any urls I access are being stopped by this error so I can't check the running schema, only via file.

Comment: @voretaq7 I haven't checked on with their devs yet.

Comment: @mikelcelestial I would check with the SOLR folks and see what they say (worst case they'll give you more stuff to try that doesn't work, but you'll be able to add more info to the question and maybe we'll come up with something. Best case they'll give you a solution and you can post an answer yourself explaining what happened and how to fix it and get free rep :-)

Answer (score -1):

From version 3.x to 4.x Solr has changed its schema.xml structure. In 4.x versions is no longer a < types> list nor < fields>, only < type> and < field> objects.

Try commenting the < types>< /types> and < fields>< /fields> pairs of tags in the schema.xml

Hope it is useful!

Comment: I don't actually see a <fields> or <types> tag in there?